# Интеграция двух сайтов на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, мобильная-разработка, интеграция

Имеется десктопный сайт интернет магазина на wordpress, нужно создать мобильный сайт на субдомене. При этом что бы у них была общая база данных и часть функционала. К примеру что был internet-magazin.com.ua и m.internet-magazin.com.ua.
Подскажите лучшее средство интеграции двух сайтов на одном wp. Желательно без wordpress multisite и без излишних плагинов. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если использование одной темы не подходит, то я бы рекомендовал использовать что-нибудь вроде WordPress Theme Switcher и менять тему по условию `array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))) = 'm'`

Comment: а домены-то как переключать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress жестко прописывает ссылки внутри базы, вместе с именем домена. Таким образом, на каждый домен нужно создавать свою базу (как в multisite). Или изобретать какие-то дикие костыли с rewrite.

Обычно на WordPress поступают иначе. Применяют адаптивную тему, которая подстраивает вывод на экран через @media в css. Такой подход дает очевидные преимущества - все в одной базе, не надо думать о синхронизации баз и т.д.

Адаптивных тем полно, как платных, так и бесплатных. Лучше смотреть в эту сторону.

Comment: Вообще-то нет никаких ни костылей ни проблем при применении указанных плагинов. Для нуба вообще всё легко и прозрачно, если не учитывать настройку алиаса на хостинге. Но это в любом случае нужно делать, так что не в счёт.

Comment: Плагины тему меняют, а сам поддомен как организовать, если без multisite?

Comment: Всё есть в плагинах. Я их юзал ещё когда адаптивных тем почти не было. Я имею ввиду - один сайт. с мобильной темой на поддомене.

Comment: Аналогично плагинам для мультиязычности.

Answer (score -1):

> При этом что бы у них была общая база данных и часть функционала. К примеру что был internet-magazin.com.ua и m.internet-magazin.com.ua. Подскажите лучшее средство интеграции двух сайтов на одном wp.

Почему двух сайтов, если это один сайт, с мобильной версией на поддомене?

Для этого есть [куча плагинов](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=mobile), которые по факту **меняют тему** для поддомена. Но попутно делают ещё кучку работы - определяют UA и пр. Нужно только выбрать что подойдёт в конкретном случае.